# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a mi wampserver desde el celular?

Tags: php, wamp, localhost

Quiero ver como se ve mi proyecto en dispositivo móvil y quiero abrirlo en el celular. Aclaro que ambos tanto pc como móvil están en la misma red.

Answer (score 1):

Esta funcion la han cambiado en la nuevas versiones del WampServer 3.1.X, 
Ahora para poner modo Online hay que hacer los siguientes pasos:

1) Click boton derecho del **mouse -> wamp setting -> (Menu item: online / offline)**

Esto reiniciara los servicios del wamp y se colocara nuevamente en verde

2) Click boton izquierdo y ahora aparece la opcion en la base del menu (Put online)

Nuevamente se reinicia los servicios del wamp pero ahora se cambia el icono verde.

3) Prueba desde el navegador de otra computadora o celular la ip de tu equipo que tiene el wamp. ej: 192.168.1.103

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en windows abre la consola y escribe **ipconfig**, busca donde diga, **direccion IPv4**

```
 Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2 (esta es mi ip)
```

y solo cambia localhost por la ip que te esta dando, de esta forma, en tu celular.

- localhost/tuproyecto
- 192.168.0.2/tuproyecto

Comment: tu respuesta es parcialmente correcta, ya que ademas de entrar por la ip debería corroborar que wamp este configurado para acceder  por la red LAN...